# White square SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I've faced with [The white square problem](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem) at SFML C++ while I'm trying to display a textured button. I've got an `ImageButton.h` which inherits from `Button.h`. The texture is loaded successfully (checked in debugger). But in the end, I see a **white square**. How to solve it?

**Button.h**

```
#ifndef BUTTON_H
#define BUTTON_H

#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Button
{
public:
    Button();
    Button(sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f pos,sf::Color outlineColor, float sizeOutline);
    void virtual draw(sf::RenderWindow* w) = 0;
protected:
    sf::RectangleShape frame;
};



#endif // !BUTTON_H
```

**Button.cpp**

```
#include "Button.h"

Button::Button()
{
}

Button::Button(sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f pos,sf::Color outlineColor, float sizeOutline)
{
    frame.setPosition(pos);
    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setOutlineColor(outlineColor);
    frame.setOutlineThickness(sizeOutline);
}
```

**ImageButton.h**

```
#ifndef IMAGE_BUTTON_H
#define IMAGE_BUTTON_H

#include"Button.h"

class ImageButton : public Button
{
public:
    ImageButton();
    ImageButton(sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color outlineColor, float sizeOutline, std::string path);
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow* w);
private:
    sf::Texture backTexture;
    sf::Sprite background;
};


#endif // !IMAGE_BUTTON_H
```

**ImageButton.cpp**

```
#include "ImageButton.h"

ImageButton::ImageButton()
{
}

ImageButton::ImageButton(sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color outlineColor, float sizeOutline, std::string path)
    : Button(size,pos,outlineColor,sizeOutline)
{
    
    backTexture.loadFromFile(path, sf::IntRect(sf::Vector2i(pos.x,pos.y),sf::Vector2i(size.x,size.y)));
    backTexture.setSmooth(true);
    background.setTexture(backTexture);
    background.setPosition(pos);
}

void ImageButton::draw(sf::RenderWindow* w)
{
    w->draw(this->background);
    w->draw(this->frame);
}
```

**programm.h**

```
#ifndef PROGRAMM_H
#define PROGRAMM_H

#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include"ImageButton.h"


class programm
{
public:
    programm();
    void run();
private:
    ImageButton b;
    sf::RenderWindow* window;
    sf::Event e;
    void render();
    void update();

};
#endif // !PROGRAMM_H
```

**programm.cpp**

```
#include "programm.h"

programm::programm()
{
    this->window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Novel Editor", sf::Style::Close);
    this->window->setPosition(sf::Vector2i(0, 0));
    this->window->setFramerateLimit(60);
    this->b = ImageButton(sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Color::Yellow, 5.f, "images\\putin.png");
}

void programm::run()
{
    while (this->window->isOpen())
    {
        while (this->window->pollEvent(e))
        {
            update();
        }
    }
}

void programm::render()
{
    this->window->clear();
    b.draw(this->window);
    this->window->display();
}

void programm::update()
{
    switch (e.type)
    {
    case sf::Event::Closed:
    {
        this->window->close();
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }

    render();
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: As I learned, SFML is building on smart pointers, so the assignment of `ImageButton` to `this->p` could work, but depends on the assignment operators of `sf::Texture` or `sf::Sprite` being correctly implemented (are they?). So I'd try to move the list of `ImageButton` constructor arguments to the initializer list `: b(<here>)`. BTW: the `new` in ```this->window = new sf::RenderWindow(...``` and `sf::RenderWindow* window;` in `program.h` seems quite inconsistent to me, it's dangerous to mix automatic and dynamic variables this way.

Comment: If you look at this https://www.reddit.com/r/sfml/comments/68hmcb/white_square_problem/ you'll see the same pattern, an automatic `Player` object is assigned to an existing one (`player`). It really looks as if there is something wrong in (at least one of) the assignment operators in `sf::Texture` and `sf::Sprite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
programm::programm()
{
    ...
    this->b = ImageButton(...); //< this line cause the bug
}
```

You are initializing your image button `this->b` by assigning from a local `ImageButton`. Now the sprite will have the texture reference of the local instance's texture, and when the local instance will "die" the texture will be freed. You need to maintain the lifetime of the texture

**Solution 1**: override the assignment operator and set texture there like this

```cpp
ImageButton& operator=(const ImageButton& ref) {
        backTexture = ref.backTexture;
        background = ref.background;
        background.setTexture(backTexture);
        return *this;
}
```

**Solution 2**: Create a `TextureManager` and make it as your texture API for all your program, maintain your texture lifetime through it.

**Solution 3**: initialize the image button at `programm` constructor

```cpp
programm::programm()
    :b (sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Color::Yellow, 5.f, "img.jpg")
{
   ...
}
```

### Another bug

```cpp
void ImageButton::draw(sf::RenderWindow* w)
{
    w->draw(this->background);
    w->draw(this->frame);
}
```

you're drawing your frame after the background, and your frame's fill color by default is white

**Solution 1**: draw frame first and draw background next

**Solution 2**: set your frame fill color alpha to 0

```cpp
Button::Button(sf::Vector2f size, sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Color outlineColor, float sizeOutline)
{
    frame.setPosition(pos);
    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setOutlineColor(outlineColor);
    frame.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); // <----
    frame.setOutlineThickness(sizeOutline);
}
```

Comment: What a detailed explanation! Seems you are familiar with the lib, I learned about it only now. Would  you say it's mature (besides the well-known white square problem)?

Comment: @Wolf thanks, I'm also just started learning SFML. Sprite's internal texture reference is just a raw pointer `const Texture* m_texture`, causing all the trouble, and we need to maintain the lifetime of the texture. just read your answer it's also well explained (+1)

Comment: **Do you maybe know if this was already addressed in some SFML bug report?** I mean, we see that the documentation fails to tell people what not to do. At least making copying private for `sf:Sprite` should be done, of course it would be better to implement the copy...

Comment: I tried to find a but report for this but nothing. Maybe not copying is for performance reasons? Using a **TextureManager** seems interesting, Here an interesting ["thread" (not too short)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/191793/31651)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you and others ([on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sfml/comments/68hmcb/white_square_problem/),
[on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsfml%5Dwhite+square+is%3AQ),
and [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=SFML+%22white+square%22))
are facing is caused by the way the constructor and assignment operator of
`sf::Sprite` are (not) implemented: Since the developers decided to not
implement specialized functions and didn't make them private, the compiler
provides defaults that are not aware of the semantics of the `m_texture`
pointer and therefore doing a binary copy. This may be not the best approach but
[it's documented](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem).

So if you are using a `sf::Sprite` member in your class without taking
special measures for copying, the compiler will assume default assignment
semantics and therefore invoke the (invalid) assignment semantics of the
`sf::Sprite` class. The local `ImageButton` object you create in the
`program` invokes this default assignment of `ImageButton`

```cpp
programm::programm()
{
    this->window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Novel Editor", sf::Style::Close);
    this->window->setPosition(sf::Vector2i(0, 0));
    this->window->setFramerateLimit(60);
    this->b = ImageButton(sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Color::Yellow, 5.f, "images\\putin.png");
}
```

the `Sprite` in member `b` takes over the pointer `texture` from the
`Sprite` within the local `ImageButton` whose lifetime is limited to the
scope of the `programm` constructor. Beyond that, the `sprite` in your
member `b` holds a reference to a destroyed texture object which causes
is undefined behaviour (see also [sf::Sprite Class Reference (SFML / Learn / 2.4.1 Documentation)](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560)):

> If the source texture is destroyed and the sprite tries to use it,
> the behavior is undefined.

By the way, I'd suggest directly using `sf::RenderWindow window` in the
`program` class not via pointer, so you could change your code to something
like this (note that I used `button` instead of `b` and shortened inlined
the implementation for the sake of brevity).

```cpp
class programm
{
public:
    programm():
        window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Novel Editor", sf::Style::Close);
        button(sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), sf::Vector2f(50.f, 50.f), 
        sf::Color::Yellow, 5.f, "images\\putin.png")
    {
        window->setPosition(sf::Vector2i(0, 0));
        window->setFramerateLimit(60);
    }
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    ImageButton button;
};
```

Another option would be to provide a specialized assignment operator
([thakee nathees shows how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65860224/2932052))
or copy constructor for your `ImageButton` class that takes care of the
deep copy of the texture object.

Alternatively, you could think about implementing a wrapper class for
`sf::Sprite` to fix this issue and use this instead for you application(s).